# A general solution for a 2d pdf (ode)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the following 2 dimensional PDE:

$$
\partial_{x_1}^2 u(x_1,x_2)+\frac{1}{x_1^2}\partial_{x_2}^2 u(x_1,x_2)+\frac{1}{x_1}\partial_{x_1}u(x_1,x_2)=k
$$
where $k>0$ is a constant, and $x_1\in[1,\infty)$, $0<x_2<1$. For boundary conditions, I have $h(1,x_2)=cos(x_2)$

I am looking for a general solution of this equation. I know how to do for the case that $k=0$ but I got confused at $k>0$. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: you can use the solutions you found for the homogeneous equation (where $k=0$) to construct the so-called Green's function. Using that, it's easy to solve the PDE for general $k$; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreensFunction.html). Note that your equation is of the form $\mathcal{L} u = f$, with $f = k$ and
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{L} u = \partial_x^2 u + \frac{1}{x^2} \partial_y^2 u + \frac{1}{x} \partial_x u.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\partial_{xx}u(x,y) + \frac{1}{x^2}\partial_{yy}u(x,y)+\frac{1}{x}\partial_x u(x,y) = 0
$$
lets assume a form of $u(x,y) = x^2v(x,y)$ we find
$$
\partial_{yy}v(x,y) + x^2\partial_{xx}v(x,y) + 5x\partial_x v(x,y) + 4v(x,y) = k
$$
you can transform to $\phi(x,y) = 4v(x,y) -k$ (assuming $k$ is a const) then we have
$$
\partial_{yy}\phi(x,y) + x^2\partial_{xx}\phi(x,y) + 5x\partial_{x}\phi(x,y) + 4\phi(x,y) =0
$$
which is separable.

Rolling back the transforms you will have
$$
u(x,y) = x^2\frac{\phi(x,y)+k}{4}
$$